# Cant get z-indexing to work to IE7

Tags: html, css

The nav works the same in every browser i've tested on a mac and pc; however, I cant for the life of me figure out why in IE7 the nav is appearing under the content in the main content block. Check out http://obs4.dynapp.net/ to see the problem, it only exist in IE7. Check out the source if your interested in helping out with the problem. I dunno, I've spent hours staring at html/css and cant figure anything out.

http://obs4.dynapp.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a seriously annoying IE7 bug. It occurs because positioned elements later in the DOM will be given priority over those earlier in the DOM, regardless of z-index status.

This article will explain how to fix it: http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000763.html

Basically, add position and z-index to the least common ancestor. So, if your header and content are both contained in a container, add position and z-index to that container. If they're direct children of the body, add it to the body.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

z-indexing is weird with IE7.  You have `position: absolute` for your nav.  You have `position: relative` for your content.  Yes, z-indexing should work where your position doesn't matter, but IE7 will take that into affect and give you two different "stacks" for z-indexes so `absolute` and `relative` positioned elements do not interact with each other.  Try giving your nav a `position: relative` instead and then readjusting your css accordingly.

Comment: Doing what you mentioned did appear to change anything, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: hmmm ok, maybe that is an IE 6 bug then...i remember there was some annoyance with that for an IE version.  Haven't worked with IE in a little bit now haha